# convolutional neural network - how filters are found/calculated

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am trying to learn convolutional neural networks from scratch.

I try to find a simple example that I can calculate by hand just to get the ideas.

There are many things that I do not understand so let's start simple.

I found some CNN examples that detect shapes like X, O, /, \ or faces like :) and :(, so just stuff that you can draw in a frame with 8x8 boxes.

In many examples filters are already given, but as I know filters are "trained" in the hidden layer via backpropagation.

So a CNN starts with filters with random values but I do not understand how the filters become what they are, I mean how a filter A becomes a detector for straight lines, or how a Filter B becomes a detector for curves.
I just know that with some "magic" you end up with different filters and each filter is unique and detects a special shape/feature.

The other thing is who is telling me how many filter the CNN should have? Is it just intuition or just testing?

Whats about the filter size, in many example I saw that the dimensions of the filters 3x3, but why not 5x5 or other dimensions?

What would really help me is a small and simple step by step example.

---

Thanks for respond Firebug!

There are many things that I still do not get and that I have to study.
For example I did not know that deep learning is largely based on heuristics/try and error.

I created a little example that I found and as you can see its very simplified
[image: enter CNN]

In this examples the filters are given and the weights are manually changed so that we get an average of 0.8 for all votes.
As far as I know I can decide what accuracy I accept, in this case we just decide that 80% is enough.

What really would help me is to see a step by step backpropagation by hand with all kernels and weights set to 1 so I can see how the kernel and the weights get the values that they get.
I would also like to see the cost-function that is optimized.

It is very abstract for me at the moment but I hope you can help me out, then I can move on to the other details.

Comment: Do you understand how a fully-connected networks learns the parameter values?

Answer (score 3):

Deep learning is largely based on heuristics today. There are no hard answers for broad questions.

> So a CNN starts with filters with random values but I do not
> understand how the filters become what they are, I mean how a filter A
> becomes a detector for straight lines, or how a Filter B becomes a
> detector for curves.

Optimization. When you present data and perform gradient descent, these types of Gabor-like filters tend to appear naturally in the first layers, implicating these forms are useful for natural images (the mammal visual system also use similar forms). There's no guarantee though.

> The other thing is who is telling me how many filter the CNN should have? Is it just intuition or just testing?

Objectively? You.

You could, ideally, perform hyper-parameter tuning to decide that, or alternatively architectural search. The point is, never base such a decision on performance in validation/testing sets, that's the greatest sin in machine learning.

> Whats about the filter size, in many example I saw that the dimensions of the filters 3x3, but why not 5x5 or other dimensions?

Again, heuristics.
Keep in mind that two 3x3 filters have the same receptive field of a 5x5 filter.
People use 3x3 most often, but many architectures employ many filter sizes as well.

Comment: Isn't hyper-parameter tuning based on the validation set performance? Completely agree that it is a huge error to change any hyperparameter based on the performance on the test set, though.

Comment: @Ciodar yes, but when I wrote this answer I was actually referring to "test sets". It's just that a lot of people will call them "validation sets" as well.